# Having problems with accessing active directory using C#

Tags: active-directory

My IS manager provided me with parameters in this format and I am trying use C# to validate a user against Active directory.

Here is a code sample (of course not the real credentials).  How do I use these parameters to against a DirectoryEntry object so I can search for users etc.

```
provider-url=ldap://email.acmetech.com:1111/
base-dn=  DC=acmetecg,DC=com
security-authentication= simple
security-principal= CN=ldap,cn=users,DC=acmetech,DC=com
security-credentials= Ldap000
```

I know this should be simple but its been years since I've programmed active directory.

Edit:  How do I pass my params to a directory entry object so I can query objects in AD?

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET 3.5 it's pretty easy.

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "acmetecg"))
{
    // check the creds (assuming ldap is the user name, and ldap000 is the password)
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("ldap", "ldap000")
}
```

Comment: Srry if i didnt ask this correctly but how do i pass my params to a directoryentry object so i can query objects in AD.